# como puedo obtener el subdominio en php

Tags: php

Como puedo obtener el nombre del subdominio en php
tengo mi script php funciona pero al poner www.sub.domain.com me toma primero www

```
<?php
$url = 'http://en.example.com';

$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);

$subdomain = $host[0];
echo $subdomain;
?>
```

quiero omitir el www

**EJEMPLO:**
*http://www.sub.localhost.com = www*

resultado que quiero es: **sub**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto te omitiría las `www` si están presentes en el string:

```
function getSubdominio($host_array) {
    $output = array_shift($host_array);
    if ($output === 'www') {
        $output = array_shift($host_array);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Con esa función declarada, puedes reemplazar esto:

```
$subdomain = $host[0];
```

...por esto:

```
$subdomain = getSubdominio($host);
```

---

** Edicion:

La solución anterior asume que sólo existe un nivel de subdominios.

Si hubiese más de uno, la función sería más versátil así:

```
function getSubdominio($host_array, $sub_level=1) {
    $idx = 1 + $sub_level;
    $inv_arr = array_reverse($host_array);
    $output = $inv_arr[$idx];
    if ($output === 'www') {
        $idx += 1;
    }
    // Si se sale del límite, cogemos el último existente
    while($idx >= sizeof($inv_arr) - 1)
    {
        $idx -= 1;
    }
    return $inv_arr[$idx];
}
```

Con eso, se podrían manejar varios niveles de subdominios. Por ejemplo, si tienes:

```
logos.en.examples.com
```

Para obtener `en`:

```
$subdomain = getSubdominio($host, 1);

//El segundo parámetro es opcional y 1 por defecto
//Se puede omitir en este caso
$subdomain = getSubdominio($host);
```

Y para obtener `logos`:

```
$subdomain =getSubdominio($host, 2);
```